# How do you save a CREATE VIEW statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

EDIT: This question was based on the incorrect premise that SQL VIEWS were cleared from a database when the user that created them disconnects from the server.  Leaving this question in existence in case others have that assumption.

I'm trying to use views in my database, but I'm running up against an inability to save the code as a SQL Server object for repeated use.

I tried saving `CREATE VIEW` statements as procedures and user defined functions, but as many have answered on stack overflow, `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` are incompatible with `CREATE VIEW` due to the only one in batch issue.

Obviously I don't want to retype my CREATE VIEW statements every time, and I'd prefer not to have to load them from text files.  I must be missing something here.

Comment: Your views are not being created? You should never need to retype a create view statement. It's similar to create table - once you create it, you have to explicitly drop it or its there permanently. (edit: I see this is tsql)

Comment: paste in your CREATE VIEW statement.

Comment: @Wes No, the views are created just fine, I can't figure out how to save the code as an object SQL Server

Comment: The view is the object, if you right-click on the view in the object explorer, you can do 'script-as' if you wanted to see/alter the view script.

Comment: @Hartco no, not the view that is created, the code to do so.  So if I need to create the view again.  Like a stored procedure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying views are objects, and object definitions are available in the db after the objects are created. You could certainly slap the code in a stored proc, if you wanted, I do that with things I'm working on all the time, but the definition is already saved.

Comment: @ReidMcCamish Why would you ever create the view again? Once its created, it's created. Do you mean creating a similar view? You should post some examples of what you are doing.

Comment: @Wes that was actually the answer I needed, I thought views were cleared on connection end

Comment: @ReidMcCamish Nope, that would be a temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to, you could create a view in a proc like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspCreateView AS 
  EXEC('CREATE VIEW...  ')
```

Though, you'll have to escape single quotes in your view code with ''

However, I have to agree with the other comments that this seems like a strange thing to do.

Some other thoughts:

You can use sp_helptext to get the code of an existing view:

```
sp_helptext '<your view name here>'
```

Also, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS includes a VIEW_DEFINITION column with the same code:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really "save" CREATE/ALTER statements.  The create or alter statement changes the structure of the database.  You can use SSMS to generate the statement again later by right clicking on the view, and choosing Script as->Create.  This inspects the structure of the database and generates the statement.

The problem with this approach is your database now consists of both a structure definition(DDL) as well as its contents, the data.  If you dropped/created the database to clear its data, you'd also have lost the structure.  So you always need a database hanging around for the structure and back it up to ensure you don't ever lose the DDL.

Personally I would use Database Projects as part of Visual Studio and SQL Server Data Tools.  This allows you to keep each View, Table, etc. as separate files, and then update the database using schema compare.  The main benefit being you can separate the definition of the database from the database itself, and also source control or backup the DDL files.

Comment: Wait, are views not cleared when the user disconnects from the database?  That was my understanding of what they were for (like 'work' library tables in SAS)

Comment: Ah that explains the confusion, views are permanent objects, they exist until you drop them, they are not like # tables that vanish.